# C# Cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Net.EndPoint'

Tags: c#, vb.net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnx9E.png

I'm converting an Open Source program from VB to C# and I'm getting this error. I've spent a good amount of time searching a solution, as-well as attempting my own solution but I've gotten no where. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The idea is to paste you code, so we don't have to squint at images among other reasons

Comment: Generally you should never use `object` if you know what the field's type actually is. Change `private object endPoint;` to `private EndPoint endPoint;`

Comment: @AlphaDelta You should post that as the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is endpoint really exists?

and is endpoint is really System.Net.EndPoint?

if then, you should change [endpoint]`s class as System.Net.EndPoint.

or use cast method as

```
client.SendTo(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(A2S_INFO), (System.Net.EndPoint)endpoint);
```

Comment: Casting endPoint to type `EndPoint` is missing the... end point. It's not necessary for the field to be of type `Object` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is this issue occurring?

The method of `Socket.SendTo` expects a parameter of type `EndPoint`, however you're passing it a field (`private object endPoint`) whose type is `Object`, which is *not* equivalent to `EndPoint`.

## Solution

The solution in this particular circumstance is to declare your `private object endPoint` as `private EndPoint endPoint`, as you know the value of the field will always be of type `EndPoint` or some inherited class of the same type.

You could also cast the field to type `EndPoint` like so: `(EndPoint)endPoint` and keep the field declared as an `Object`. However generally a variable should never be of type `Object` if you're aware of what the type of the variable actually is. `Object` is only used in circumstances where the type of the value is unknown.